# RightToLeft RichTextBox with pre-loaded text

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

Ok i found a strange type of bug in MS default Richtextbox in vb.net 2008. If we add some line of text in Richtextbox programmaticlly. there is a gape from right side. see the image below

[image: ٰerror]

here is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As New Form
    Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
    f.Width = 500
    f.Height = 500
    rtb.RightToLeft = Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
    For i = 1 To 20
        rtb.AppendText("بسم اللہ الرحمن الرحیم" & vbNewLine)
    Next
    rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    f.Controls.Add(rtb)
    f.Show()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain it, but try changing the order of your code so that the RichTextBox control is added to the form *before* you append the text.  This worked for me:

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
  Dim f As New Form
  f.Width = 500
  f.Height = 500

  Dim rtb As New RichTextBox
  rtb.Name = "rtb"
  rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
  rtb.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes

  f.Controls.Add(rtb)
  For i = 1 To 25
    rtb.AppendText("بسم اللہ الرحمن الرحیم" & vbNewLine)
  Next
  f.Show()

  f.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of RichTextBox)(AddressOf RunFix), rtb)
End Sub

Sub RunFix(ByVal rtfControl As RichTextBox)
  rtfControl.Select(0, 0)
  rtfControl.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

I added a hack `BeginInvoke` method that performs a `ScrollToCaret()` call which *seems* to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work all the time. I have a much complex code, in that code i load the rtf from file it dose not work there.

Comment: @user934820 Looks like a buggy scrollbar issue.  My example works, but if I change the `f.Height = 250`, then it doesn't.  If I resize the form with my mouse, it fixes itself.

Comment: yes its true, i also realize that, and one thing more if we add just one line this error will never appears. So if there is any proper solution for this bug or else my app which is for reading the text is useless.

Comment: @user934820 Updated answer with a new hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you also set

```
rtb.Width = 500
rtb.Height = 500
```

Then it works as desired.

I agree it is strange behaviour. It does the same with VS 2012 RC.